# Problem with Telnet

Tags: cisco

I have 10 routers(R1 to R10),OSPF run between them and telnet is enabled on all.sometimes when i try telnet to R10 from R1, it rejects.

the solution that is used to overcome this,is first ping R10 from R1 and when try telnet again,problem is solved and telnet accepted. why?
(somebody tell me perhaps mac-address-table cause it)
[image]

Comment: Is this a real network or a simulated one? For the latter, I'm guessing it's a  simulation glitch.

Comment: Or software bug.. What model routers are they and what switches? What software version are they running?

Comment: It happen in a real network.the name of routers is not real here.the routers and switches model are 7200 and nexus 3000 respectively.also sometimes when i telnet to switches the problem may happen.

Comment: Can you see what source IP address is used for telnet? I'd run a packet trace on the SW1-R1 port to check if ARP works and which source IP address is used.

Comment: Did you get a "connection refused" message or a "connection timeout" message?

Comment: i use securecrt to telnet it and when problem happen i don't get any message.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly seems that this is an ARP resolution issue. Try placing a static ARP entry on the 2 routers just to test, and see if you continue to have the issue. If you don't then it is entirely possible the ARP resolution is just not happening fast enough.

Comment: What are the link medias for the connections between devices? Also, by rejected do you mean the connection attempt times out, or you are actually getting a rejected message?